# PowerMock can mock final class, PowerMockito cannot

Tags: powermock, spock, powermockito

I have a final class I need to mock, so I turned to PowerMock. I find EasyMock-style syntax unreadable, so I'm trying to use PowerMockito.

Full disclosure, I'm doing this in Spock, which means I can't use a PowerMock runner, but I've got the rule in place, so that problem is solved. And yes, I've tried Groovy mocks, but they can't handle Java final classes.

Here's a sketch of the working version:

```
@PrepareForTest([Final.class])
class MapperTest extends Specification {

@Rule PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule()

def testIt() {
  given:
  def fin = PowerMock.createMock(Final.class)
  ...
```

This version, which I've cloned from examples on the web, bombs:

```
@PrepareForTest([Final.class])
class MapperTest extends Specification {

@Rule PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule()

def testIt() {
  given:
  def fin = PowerMockito.mock(Final.class)
  ...
```

I get the following exception at runtime:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/mock/MockName
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:143)
```

Tearing my hair out over this. Thanks if you can help!

**Update:** I tried this in JUnit, same problem.

Comment: this is a class loader issue. If you are using maven, remove mockito dependencies that are explicitly defined in your pom. Give only powermockito dependencies which internally pulls the compatible mockito dependencies.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Orbfish does above solution works for you? 
Kswaughs, I have mockito dependency as follows
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
How can I replace this with powermock?

Comment: Honestly, I never tried it and I forget where I stored the case, so I can't answer that question.